# why does the Director class make my global variables not visible to external modules in corona?

Tags: global-variables, coronasdk

I'm doing basic stuff to understand using external classes/modules with global variables, and now I'm trying to add director. But when I added the director class, my global variables such as applyThrust then became not visible in the external class.

It worked fine before refactoring for Director. Before using director, I only had 2 files, rocket.lua and the mainScreen.lua file below was simply main.lua. I used the same globals, applyThrust and thrustForceY, and it worked.

By the way, the director functionality of switching screens appears to work fine, other than this odd side effect of making the global variables not visible.

I asked this on the corona director forums and got no response so I thought I'd try reliable STO.

Here's the files I'm using with the director stuff :

main.lua

```
display.setStatusBar (display.HiddenStatusBar)

local director = require ("director")
local mainGroup = display.newGroup()

local function main()
    mainGroup:insert(director.directorView)
    director:changeScene("menu")
    return true
end

main()
```

menu.lua

```
module(..., package.seeall)

function new()
    local localGroup = display.newGroup()
    ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    local playText = display.newText("Play",160, 100, "Arial", 32)
    playText:setTextColor(0, 0, 255)
    localGroup:insert(playText)

    local function pressPlay (event)
        if event.phase == "ended" then
            director:changeScene ("mainScreen")
        end
    end

    playText:addEventListener ("touch", pressPlay)

    ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    return localGroup
end
```

mainScreen.lua

```
local Rocket = require( "rocket" )
local physics = require( "physics" )
module(..., package.seeall)

function new()
    local localGroup = display.newGroup()
    ------------------------------------------------------------------
    score = 100

    physics.start()

    local ground = display.newRect( 60, 170, 60, 60 )
    physics.addBody( ground, "static", { density=3.0, friction=0.5, bounce=0.2 } )

    rocket = Rocket.new(80, 110)

    local upText = display.newText("Up",160, 300, "Arial", 32)
    upText:setTextColor(0, 0, 255)

    ------------- my global variables  -----------
    thrustForceY = -100
    applyThrust = false

    local function pressUp (event)
        local t = event.target

        local phase = event.phase
        if( "began" == phase ) then
            display.getCurrentStage():setFocus( t )
            t.isFocus = true

            if( not applyThrust ) then
                rocket:addThrust()
            end
            rocket:applyForce(0, thrustForceY, rocket.x, rocket.y)
            applyThrust = true
        elseif "ended" == phase or "cancelled" == phase then
            rocket:removeThrust()
            display.getCurrentStage():setFocus( nil )
            t.isFocus = false
            applyThrust = false
        end
        return true
    end

    upText:addEventListener ("touch", pressUp)

    ----------------------------------------------
    return localGroup
end
```

rocket.lua

```
module(..., package.seeall)
local physics = require( "physics" )

--constructor--------------------
function new(x, y) 
    rocket = display.newGroup()

    local body = display.newRect( x, y, 25, 60 )
    physics.addBody( body, { density=1.5, friction=0.5, bounce=0.2 } )
    body.isFixedRotation = true
    rocket:insert(body)

    local thrust = {}

    function rocket:addThrust()
        thrust = display.newRect( body.x, body.y + (body.height / 2) , 10, 10 )
        thrust.y = body.y + (body.height / 2) + (thrust.height / 2)
        physics.addBody( thrust, { density=1.5, friction=0.5, bounce=0.2 } )
        rocket:insert(thrust)
    end

    function rocket:removeThrust()
        rocket:remove(thrust)
    end

    function rocket:applyForce( xForce, yForce, atPointX, atPointY )
        body:applyForce( xForce, yForce, atPointX, atPointY )
    end

    ----------------------------------------------------------------------
    --      enterFrame listener for rocket
    ----------------------------------------------------------------------

    function rocket:enterFrame (event)

        if( applyThrust ) then
            body:applyForce(0, thrustForceY, body.x, body.y)
            thrust.y = body.y + (body.height / 2) + (thrust.height / 2)
            thrust.x = body.x
        else
            print("applyThrust is nil")
        end

    end

    Runtime:addEventListener("enterFrame", rocket)

    return rocket
end
```

Answer (score 0):

A global variable in Corona is as simple as using "_G." before your variable.

For example:

```
lives = 3
```

Would become:

```
_G.lives = 3
```

But Director already has functionality to pass parameters to another scene.... there is no need to use globals.

**scene1.lua**

```
local params = {
       param1= "http://github.com/",
       param2 = "bla-bla"
}
director:changeScene( params, "screen2", "moveFromRight" )
```

**screen2.lua**

```
new = function ( params )

        local url = params.param1
        local bla = params.param2
        ...
end
```

Comment: I didn't know global variables 'became' _G.myVar; I was trying to avoid _G usage because I thought I read that as a best practice; nevertheless, thanks for your response about the param passing in Director; I'll try that, but that's not exactly the issue; the issue is between global vars between the mainScreen.lua and the rocket.lua

Answer (score 0):

Good point.

Also, you can put all your variables in a file you created and access it from any module.